# Why when I try to join a low poly tree with icospheres they get distorted

Tags: modeling, materials

I have created a low poly tree using icospheres as the leaves.

I'm trying to do an <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> to join and get one object and when I do so the icospheres get distorted.

I don't know what is causing it. When I did an <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> (join) on another tree I created (didn't have icoshperes but in the same project), that tree survived the process.

Before join
[image]

After join
[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? (v 2.92.0)

Comment: Are there any modifiers in the icospheres/tree? If there is, then the icospheres could be inheriting it.

Comment: Looks like an edge split modifier + smooth modifier by the looks of it :)

Comment: I fixed it. I think the problem was I applied a skin modifier to the tree trunk/branches and didn't actually "Apply" it. So it was never considered permanent. Once I actually clicked apply  and then did the join, it worked. Probably a newbie mistake but thanks for replying.